# How can I align a span inside an anchor tag to use all the width it is given?

Tags: html, css

right now I got this problem:

I have an `<a>` tag, and inside of that I want to display a bit of text, and then a `<span>` with a unicode, which I want to display at the very right possible in my `<a>` tags width.

I got a fiddle for you here: [Click me](https://jsfiddle.net/j6wp75xu/1/)

The dropdown-button you can see next to my regular text is not abusing all the width, despite the `text-align: right`.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You want .textAlignRight at right ? Add float right ?

Comment: During i test it and make a jsfiddle you already have few answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.textAlignRight{
float:right;
}
```

instead of `text-align`

```css
.anchor{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.textAlignRight{
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<a class="anchor" href="#"> Blabla
    <span class="textAlignRight">&#9013;</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use floats for this. You are currently trying to have text within an element both left *and* right aligned- which you cant do, instead, `float:right` the icon:

### [Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j6wp75xu/3/)

```
.anchor {
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.textAlignRight {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this option you just have to change .textAlignRight float property :

```
.anchor {
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.textAlignRight {
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered with the `float: right` option which is the easiest method but another possibility, just for fun, is using the `:after` selector.

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/j6wp75xu/5/

css

```
.anchor{
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.anchor:after {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    content: "\9013";  /* the \ and the number is all you need for displaying unicode in css content */
}
```

html

```
<a class="anchor" href="#">Blabla</a>
```